# Redux state value used as a style property value?

Tags: reactjs, redux, styles, native

I am using redux to store a hex color value like (#000000). I have many buttons that dispatch an action which is the value of the color of the button (red button dispatches red color) My component now has access to the state, but when I go to use the state for styling the backgroundColor, I get an error of undefined! My component does render the value in a text tag, so I know it is returning the proper hex value. The only thing I can think of is perhaps because it is not wrapper in strings? I tried doing this:

```
const primaryColor = this.props.theme;

const styles = {
  backgroundColor: primaryColor
}
```

I get the error: Cannot read property 'theme' of undefined

Here is my Theme.js file:

```
class Themes extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{this.props.theme}</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => 
this.props.themeColorValue('#3498db')}>Blue</Button>
        <Button onPress={() => 
this.props.themeColorValue('#e67e22')}>Orange</Button>
        <Button onPress={() => 
this.props.themeColorValue('#9b59b6')}>Purple</Button>
      </View>

   );
  }
}

const primaryColor = this.props.theme;

const styles = {
  container: {
    backgroundColor: primaryColor,
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },

};


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    theme: state.themeColorValue,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ themeColorValue: themeColorValue }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Themes);
```

Thanks to anybody who can help me solve this issue, Cheers.

Comment: Can I see your render method? Also, how are you updating state.theme? Because if you're using redux, the color should've been passed through props (mapStateToProps)

Comment: Hi Gustavo. I just added my render method in my post. I am using mapStateToProps too. If you look at the <Text> tag, the proper value is being outputed when I click on each button, this is how I know my state is being passed correctly to my component. Thank you for having a look into this!

Comment: You're using this.props in your render method and this.state in the first code snippet. Where are you using setState to save the theme value into the component state?

Comment: Sorry Josh good catch, I just fixed it that was a typo on my part!

Comment: Yes, that's your error, you're outputting state.theme instead of props.theme, that's why it shows you undefined

Comment: Sorry Gustavo, I typed the question manually I do have this.props.theme and not this.state.theme. My mistake - question has been updated

Comment: Where is the const primaryColor? Outside of the component class? (Which would be out of scope)

Comment: Yes, I have the const primaryColor and styles object directly under the component class

Comment: Where? In the constructor? In a specific life cycle method? Be specific please :)

Comment: I just updated my question to give you a better idea, thank you both Joshua and Gustavo for this help!

Comment: there seems no context for `const primaryColor = this.props.theme;
`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const primaryColor = this.props.theme;

const styles = {
  container: {
    backgroundColor: primaryColor,
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },

};
```

Move this part to the beginning of the render function, then your code should work.

Comment: Nailed it, thank you Benjamin! Joshua you were on track as well for this. Cheers!

Comment: No problem. I'm glad to help.

Comment: Another question for you. Will my app slow down a lot by doing this on every component which is about 6? (by having my styles object in render method and applying mapStateToProps other redux functionality to every component?

Comment: I don't think it will affect the speed a lot. It seems most of the styles are constant, and you could put that in a css file and only change the color inline.